# How can I break the sleep when I pressed a button on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `sensor()` method, and I use `root.after(200, sensor)` to run it all the time. I also have a function `set_speed()` in it which can set the speed of motor. When the sensor detects something, it will run

```
set_speed(100)
sleep(3)
set_speed(0)
```

Now I need to add another button, when the sensor detects something, we can press the button the break the sleep (bu the sensor is still running).

It seems that I need to add another root.after to create another thread or something, I have tried for a while but was not able to complete it.

Comment: You can't use `sleep` with tkinter. Replace that with another `root.after`, and if you want to cancel it, use `root.after_cancel`. If you want a more specific answer you will have to show us a [mcve].

Comment: You can't. Sleep does exactly what it says, it puts your entire program to sleep (meaning: it can't respond to mouse and keyboard events)

Comment: Thanks, so I need to use two root.after(), one is for set_speed(100) and another one is after the first one, so that I can represent the behavior of the sleep, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. We can simply use another after to build another thread which will be run 3 seconds later and set the speed as 0.

```
    set_speed(100)
    root.after(3000, stop)   

.....

def stop():
    set_speed(0)
```